# I want to extract the values of the Object parsee in given code. Is there any way to only get the values of each object property

Tags: node.js

```
var http = require('http'); //importing  http module
var fs = require('fs');//importing fs aka file-system module
var url = require('url');
var adr = 'https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/projects/?sort=newest&lang=nodejs';
var parsee = url.parse(adr, true);

var connc = http.createServer(reception);
function reception(request, response) {
    for (const property in parsee) {
        let jso = JSON.stringify(parsee.property);
        response.write(jso);
    }
    response.end();
}
connc.listen(8000, (error) => {
    if (!error)
        console.log("screw it , let's do it");
    else
        console.log("bad server");
});
```

When i run the above code it generates an error i.e 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
so , please tell me how can i extract values of given object.

Answer (score 0):

replace above for..in loop with

```
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(parsee)) {
    let jso = JSON.stringify(key);
    let jso1 = JSON.stringify(value);
    response.write(jso+":"+jso1+"\n");
}
```